# In Sitecore, how do I assign an HTML Editor Profile to a user or role?

Tags: sitecore, rte, security-roles

I've found plenty of documentation about assigning the **global** RTE profile (e.g. "Rich Text Default"), but no documentation on assigning specific RTE profiles to **specific user roles**. Ideally I'm looking for something accessible within the Desktop application, but I'll take any solution that involves changes to the Web.config file, or even programmatic changes if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may need to do is pick the most liberal profile that you need and set that as your global RTE profile. Then assign permissions to the individual aspects of that profile for specific user roles (e.g. deny read on certain buttons or groups of buttons). I haven't tried this myself but the granular nature of Sitecore permissions should allow you to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The curse of SO is finding your own answer only after posting the question:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=17458

> Just have one profile that includes everything, but deny everyone read
>   or break security inheritance. Then admin has everything and everyone
>   else has nothing. Add rights for the various roles as required.

This involves using the Security Editor and drilling down in the core database to:

`/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/<your global profile>/Toolbar 1/`
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/<your global profile>/Toolbar 2/`
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/<your global profile>/Toolbar 3/`

...and denying "Read" rights for user roles.